# Can I execute my unit test methods with stubs/shims commands in VS 2012 Professional?, those created in VS 2012 ultimate though

Tags: visual-studio-2012, stub, shim, microsoft-fakes

I created my unit test methods with stubs/shims in VS 2012 ultimate.

Can I execute my test methods with stubs/shims commands in VS 2012 Professional?

Comment: Similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/a/11144024/333082

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The Ultimate license is required to create the Fakes reference structure. Once that is in place, anyone can run the unit tests.

**Edit**: Per the link supplied in the comments from MSDN, I am completely wrong... It appears that unit tests with shims/stubs cannot be ran unless you have an Ultimate license. Odd that.

**Edit 2.0**: After speaking with members of me team, it appears there is a work around. If any member of your team has an Ultimate license, you can install Ultimate on the build server and use that to run your shims/stubs unit tests.

Comment: aclear, Thanks for your quick reply. But here I am just making sure that Icould able to explain my scenario better. I created the shim/stub using ultimate edition. Then I given the same solution contains shim/sub Ref. to a developer who has only professional edition in his system [no ultimate edition here]. Can he able to run test methods wiht shim/stub commands?

Comment: I am not a MS Licensing expert, however I am 99% certain that the Ultimate license is only required to create the test (specifically the adding the fakes reference structure), not run the test. I'm also fairly certain that after the fakes reference structure is created, anyone can create a shim or stub that uses those references. However, I would suggest speaking with your MS representative for clarification if you do not have both an Ultimate and a Professional license already to test on.

Comment: Thank you all. We can't do this as per MS here http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sv-FI/vstest/thread/9720eadf-68b3-4dca-9c31-2f3985c222df?prof=required